# Corp Software - Collaborative help?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, manual, collaborative

(.NET WinForms + Web)

We have a lot of apps in the company and little to no help for 400 users. We'd like to add a 'write help' button to each panel in each app that when pressed lets the user add their own help , record a how-to video etc to let our hundreds of users actually write/record the help guide for the apps. Social media meets insurance software.

Is there an open source project that would help us do this? Perhaps a commercial sharepoint plug in that helps collect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DokuWiki as it seems to be free and has good editing features.